# Offline HTML5 website with JavaScript search

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple website that needs to be able to run completely offline if needs be.  With the intention of being a 50+ page searchable reference manual.

I need the whole site to be cached upon opening one page.  I'm doing this with the appcache manifest and getting the site to cache and be viewed on an offline mobile seems to work ok.

The site has a basic JavaScript search facility (that was a freeware download) and while online this search works perfectly.  As soon as the internet connection is stopped and the cached version is used the search no longer works, displaying one of two symptoms 1. Button is clicked and nothing happens or 2. A 'webpage cannot be found' kind of error is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache#Gotchas

> Never access cached files by using traditional GET parameters (like
>   other-cached-page.html?parameterName=value). This will make the
>   browser bypass the cache and attempt to get it from network. To link
>   to cached resources that have parameters parsed in JavaScript use
>   parameters in the hash part of the link, such as
>   other-cached-page.html#whatever?parameterName=value.

But that is exactly what your js-search does. It tries to load the subpages like this "http://www.filemanage.co.uk/offline/index.html?1350563635665" using XHR.

As a fix try this

```
// change in function sendRequest line 228 from 
this.httpRequest.open("GET", uri+"?"+q, true);
// to
this.httpRequest.open("GET", uri, true);
```

Comment: Ah that make a lot sense!  I will update this now and get back.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok i changed that line.  Now the search does nothing at all.  I have FireBug which I use all the time but didn't know how to use it to debug JS just knew I could view the JS.

Comment: Yes it fails to find the form "searchengine" in line 41 and doesn't continue. Change the form name from "derletztekicksearchengine" to "searchengine".

Comment: Well that was clearly me being an idiot and not being careful what I was doing. You were right, of course, and renaming the form has solved that issue. The test site now works great! It caches fine and the site search works when not connected to the internet. Many many thanks.